# Make Div appear after scrolling past the bend

Tags: jquery

I want replicate the technique used in the site below so that after the viewer scrolls past the fold, a div is automatically displayed.

http://www.talentgarden.it/it/#!/home

I am familiar with hiding divs using jquery and using the scrollTop function, but I am not sure exactly how to let jquery know that the user has passed the fold.

I am a noob so any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 1):

He is using ScrollSpy.
See http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-scrollspy

Comment: Do I have to include the "The MooTools JavaScript Class" into my site? Or just the text from the examples? Thanks!

Comment: mootools is included in the examples

Comment: Thanks @mightyuhu  

Hate to ask, but is there any way you could provide a fiddle for this? Or please save mine? http://jsfiddle.net/YC2Lh/

I replaced the image link with the one he actually used on his site (http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/peter-right.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

this is the code I use (got it from somewhere)

```
var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), docheight = $(document).height(), winheight = $(window).height();
if  ((wintop/(docheight-winheight)) > scrolltrigger) {...}
```

where scrolltrigger is the % of page when the action happens. So, if you want it to happen after 95% of the page shows, have scrolltrigger = .95

Comment: so if scrolltrigger is greater than 95% then how do i fire an event to show a div?

Comment: var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), 
    docheight = $(document).height(), 
    winheight = $(window).height();

    if  ((wintop/(docheight-winheight)) > scrolltrigger) {.95}

    $('.target').show();

Answer (score 0):

It appears that they are checking the position of the top of the div against the bottom of the window. Once the div has scrolled up past a certain point the div appears.